# Could not find net.shibboleth.tool:xmlsectool:2.0.0

Tags: java, security, gradle, pac4j

Story: My Java is Gradle based project. Using pac4j dependency
Here is my gradle configuration:

```
compile ('org.pac4j:pac4j-saml:3.0.0-RC1'){
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
    exclude group: 'org.apache.santuario', module: 'xmlsec'
    exclude group: 'org.springframework', module: 'spring-core'
}

compile ('org.pac4j:pac4j-oauth:3.0.0-RC1')
compile ('org.pac4j:j2e-pac4j:4.0.0-RC1')
```

But I want to update pac4j dependencies because of security vulnerabilities, so I updated pac4j to the latest version which is `4.0.0-RC3`

but now when I clean build my project is showing following error.

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':compileClasspath'.
   > Could not find net.shibboleth.tool:xmlsectool:2.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/shibboleth/tool/xmlsectool/2.0.0/xmlsectool-2.0.0.pom
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/net/shibboleth/tool/xmlsectool/2.0.0/xmlsectool-2.0.0.jar
       - https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/~/maven/v1/net/shibboleth/tool/xmlsectool/2.0.0/xmlsectool-2.0.0.pom
       - https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/~/maven/v1/net/shibboleth/tool/xmlsectool/2.0.0/xmlsectool-2.0.0.jar
     Required by:
         project : > org.pac4j:pac4j-saml:4.0.0-RC1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

please help me, let me know where I am wrong.

Actually I am not able to understand the error.

Answer (score 3):

Shibboleth does not publish to maven central. [See here](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/DEV/Use+of+Maven+Central)

To get the dependency you need to add this to your resolvers in your gradle file:

```
maven { url "https://build.shibboleth.net/nexus/content/groups/public" }
```